# datetimepicker calendar not showing

Tags: php

I found this site

> https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

And I'm trying to implement one of the code in the website which is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's a linked DateTime Picker and I did write some code in the header to make it work but sadly the calendar thingy is still not showing after a few attempts. Strangely enough the datetime picker calendar shows on some other code i found but i specifically want this one to use.

the link/scripts i wrote in the header was

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As I've mentioned earlier, some other datetimepicker codes i found work this but it doesn't work on eonasdan's code.

Comment: Did you get any error in console?

Comment: Why don't you try with `type="date"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use all links properly from your reference `jquery` link should be first then you have to use other links in your `html` `head`

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>




<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' onkeydown="return false" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' onkeydown="return false" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Udhay, Thank you this solved my problem! I realized that I maybe missing some link(s) and the links aren't sorted properly.

Comment: Sir if you don't mind me asking, I tried to disable the textbox in the datetimepicker6 and 7 using readonly='true' only to find out that it disables the calendar pop-up. Is there any alternative for the readonly command?

Comment: did you tried `disabled="true"` or `disabled="disabled"` for text box. do you want disable the textbox but not datetimepicker

Comment: I've tried disabled=''true'' either but it disables both the textbox and the datetimepicker. And yes i only want to disable the textbox

Comment: @Macher use `onkeydown="return false"` in your input it will works for you or check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to add **bootstrap-datetimepicker.js** Also I have noted that your jquery has been added at the end so please change it to the first position of jquery.

Please add this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Example : https://codepen.io/mamjad00/pen/YqOWav

Comment: Hi thank you for this and the link you provided. It helped me!